# Is there another way to parse an MDB without (py)pyodbc?

Tags: python

I have to deploy a script which pulls info from a MDB file. This script is going to be deployed to over 400 XP machines that don't have an access driver and can't have it downloaded. Is there any other way to query an MDB file?

Essentially, each box uses a tool that saves a series of logs as an mdb. I need to run several queries which determines the health of the box.

As an example I'd run something like:

```
'SELECT DISTINCT DEVICE FROM DATA_MONITOR WHERE EVENT = 0'
```

Which would give me a list of devices that are running correctly.

Comment: well, you are literaly scruwed if you are working with access... the only independent way that I know is using Jython with the UCanAccess JDBC driver.

Comment: @Cesar That was my fear...mdb: the devils format.